# Anylogic convert ALP from Version 8.3.2 to 7.1.2

Tags: version, simulation, anylogic, xml.modify

I have a Simulation running in the Version 8.3.2 of Anylogic. But now I want to change it to 7.1.2. Are there any possibilities, by changing some code in the ALP manually?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you mean ALP, not APL, right?

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

- Open the .alp file in a text editor
- replace AnyLogicVersion and AlpVersion with 7.3 values, e.g.:

  - AnyLogicVersion="7.3.7.201706091033" AlpVersion="7.3.0"
- remove the entire section "RunConfiguration".

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the entire section"? I changed the AnyLogic Version and the AlpVersion but if I try to open it, it says: "error... empty String". Thanks for your help.

Comment: hu, seems SOF doesn't print "<RunConfiguration> " properly, it deleted that bit, likely due to the ">" signs. Anyway, amended the reply, sorry about that :-)

Comment: I tried that. But it still says " error... empty String".

Comment: you probably messed up some formatting. Check exactly how the text looked before. Ideally, just replace the version numbers manually, steer clear of the "-signs. And you need to delete the entire RunConfiguration section, including its heading line ("<RunConfiguration>" and closing line ("</RunConfiguration")

Comment: I tried it again but its still the same error. Now I have tried it with an empty model, there it worked but just because I copied the "Simulation Expirement" part from the old one in the new.

Comment: ok, you should ask support@anylogic.com to help you in this specific case, then.